# How to avoid key-copying when using Boost.bimap?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm [using Boost.bimap for implementing a LRU cache](http://timday.bitbucket.org/lru.html) with some *complex key* containing a string.

The problem is that the key is copied every-time I'm invoking find(). I would like to avoid this un-necessary copy (and in general: make as few as possible copies of the string, maybe via templates?)

A minimal test-case (with a [gist version](https://gist.github.com/arielm/8416549)):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/set_of.hpp>

class Test
{
public:
    struct ComplexKey
    {
        std::string text;
        int dummy;

        ComplexKey(const std::string &text, int dummy) : text(text), dummy(dummy) {}

        ~ComplexKey()
        {
            std::cout << "~ComplexKey " << (void*)this << " " << text << std::endl;
        }

        bool operator<(const ComplexKey &rhs) const
        {
            return tie(text, dummy) < tie(rhs.text, rhs.dummy);
        }
    };

    typedef boost::bimaps::bimap<
    boost::bimaps::set_of<ComplexKey>,
    boost::bimaps::list_of<std::string>
    > container_type;

    container_type cache;

    void run()
    {
        getValue("foo", 123); // 3 COPIES OF text
        getValue("bar", 456); // 3 COPIES OF text
        getValue("foo", 123); // 2 COPIES OF text
    }

    std::string getValue(const std::string &text, int dummy)
    {
        const ComplexKey key(text, dummy); // COPY #1 OF text
        auto it = cache.left.find(key); // COPY #2 OF text (BECAUSE key IS COPIED)

        if (it != cache.left.end())
        {
            return it->second;
        }
        else
        {
            auto value = std::to_string(text.size()) + "." + std::to_string(dummy); // WHATEVER...
            cache.insert(typename container_type::value_type(key, value)); // COPY #3 OF text

            return value;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Bimap is not using the `std:map` directly (I'm saying this because you are using `set_of`) but rather creates views via different container adaptors and in the process the keys are copied. It's not possible to significantly improve performance the way you've defined bimap in the question.

To obtain better performance from bimap with respect to the *ComplexKey* you will rather have to store a pointer to the *ComplexKey* (preferably raw; no ownership of the keys implied by the bimap) and provide your own sorters. Pointers are cheap to copy, the downside is that you'll have to manage the keys lifetime in parallel to the map.

Do something along the lines of,

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<ComplexKey>> ComplexKeyOwningContainer;
typedef boost::bimaps::bimap<
    boost::bimaps::set_of<ComplexKey*, ComplexKeyPtrSorter>,
    boost::bimaps::list_of<std::string>
    > container_type;
```

Note that if you are after performance you also need to be careful about `std::string` which is the other side of your bimap. They can be quite expensive, temporaries are frequent, and they will suffer from same issues as the *ComplexKey* key.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure it makes sense to use pointers for ComplexKey. Afterall, I'm using Boost.bimap because it allows to create a LRU cache in a very simple and easy-to-maintain fashion. The "big picture" is that I can live with a few extra string copying as long as my cache is ~25 times faster than the non-cached version (I just wish I could understand why find() is copying the key...) Final note concerning "the other side" of the bimap: the given code is a minimal test-case. In the real-thing: I'm using a shared_ptr.